# Check whether ostream << T is defined for class T

Tags: c++

Is there a way to check whether ostream << T is defined for a class T and use that info in deciding whether to construct a template?

For example, let us say I got some wrapper class around different types of T

```
template<class T>
Wrapper
{
public:

    T m_value;

    Wrapper(const T & value) : m_value{ value } { }
};
```

and I want to define an operator<<() friend function for printing to ostream

```
template<class T>
ostream & operator<<(ostream & out, const Wrapper<T> & wrapper)
{
    out << wrapper.value;

    return out;
}
```

Is there a way to only construct that template for types T which have ostream << T defined?

Comment: There are ways to creates traits that checks for the existence of member function and non-member functions. And you need to check for both. I'm not personally good at that kind of meta-programming, but there should be plenty of examples around if you search a little, especially here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Something like `template <class T, class = decltype(std::declval<std::ostream>() << std::declval<Wrapper<T>>().value)> ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A blueprint for doing something like that is to start with this:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, typename=void>
struct can_output_to_ostream : public std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct can_output_to_ostream<T, std::void_t
               <decltype(std::declval<std::ostream &>() <<
                     std::declval<T &&>())>>
    : public std::true_type{};


struct x {};

int main()
{
    std::cout << can_output_to_ostream<int>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << can_output_to_ostream<x>::value << std::endl;
}
```

`std::void_t` is `C++17`, but a brief search will find examples of implementing it in earlier C++ revisions.

The output of this example is:

```
1
0
```

because you can `<<` an `int`, but there's no such overload defined for `x`.

In your case, you can use this example and have your wrapper class inherit from a `implements_output_to_ostream` class that's defined in the similar manner. The default implementation does nothing, and the one for a `<<` capable class implements the `<<` operator accordingly.

Your `Wrapper` class inherits from `implements_output_ostream`. Perhaps your `Wrapper` class will provide its own `<<` method that passes its member to the parent class's method, which will be fully defined for a `<<` capable class, and undefined otherwise, causing a compilation error if an attempt is made to reference it for a class that does not implement the `<<` overload.

Comment: Thanks. This looks very promising. I will look into it.

Comment: It`s alive! *evil laughter* Once may plans of world domination come to fruition I will show myself grateful.